# Performing JOIN operations in Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I have following entities:

```
@Entity
class Blog {
    @Id
    Long blogId;

    @Index
    int numViews;
}

@Entity
class Viewer {
    @Id
    Long viewerId;

    @Index
    Long blogId;
}
```

I want to perform the following query in datastore.

*List all the blogs which have been viewed for more than a specific number of times and which have not been viewed by a particular viewerID*

Can somebody please provide a pointer on how to proceed with this? I am new to Datastore and am not able to figure out a way.

Comment: you cant. you are thinking on sql. you need to structure your data based on nosql.

Comment: @ZigMandel I added a list of Viewer field in my Blog entity but it still doesn't solve the issue since the != operator doesn't work as expected in this case. I cannot seem to think of a data model in which my query can be performed in the datastore. Even the parent child relationship doesn't seem to help here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: using a list of viewers is not scalable and seems will make the index big (exploding?).

Assuming users view few blogs compared to total blogs, maybe just filter with datastore on numViews, then manually skip those viewed by the user in the few seconds the frontend instance will give you. Could fail on users that view a lot of blogs. You might need to do this from task queues to cover all special cases that will cause a timeout.

Comment: @ZigMandel, thank you. This seems too messy with Datastore. I am thinking of using Cloud SQL for this. Thank you for your help.